# Cakephp Find doesn't output correct data

Tags: mysql, cakephp, find

I'm trying to create a query using several form inputs in cakephp.

In this form the user can use some values which i want to use to filter the results from my subscriptions.

From the form i receive 4 values which i want to use.

My find method looks like this:

```
$subscriptions = $this->set('subscriptions',
    $this->Subscription->find('all', [
        'conditions' => array(
            'and' => array(
                'Subscription.provider' => $provider,
                'Subscription.subscription_duration' => $length,
                'Subscription.subscription_allowance_minutes >=' => $minutes,
                'Subscription.subscription_allowance_sms >=' => $sms,
                'Subscription.package_internet_bundle_mb >=' => $data
            )
        ),
        'order' => 'Abonnement.subscription_price ASC'
    ])
);
```

As you can see i want to query the set value and everything higher then that to give the user a broader selection.

The $provider and $length are arrays and contains, "Vodafone", "Ben", "Tele2", "T-Mobile" etc. There is no problem with these two values but with the ones with which i want to query equals and greater then.

As i am a starter with cakephp i would like someone to verify if my find method is correct? if it's correct i will troubleshoot further and post the rest.

Comment: _There is a problem with this, somehow the equal or greater then doesn't work correct._ You are not describing your problem well enough for anyone to troubleshoot. If changing your greater than operators to less than operators does not fix the problem, then you need to better describe your problem. For instance, show sample data, along with sample selection criteria (i.e., $provider, $length, etc) and your expected results. Or show the Cakephp generated SQL and describe how you would like it to be.

Comment: Also: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the breaking filter was the fact that i was trying to query a varchar field with integers. There is a model field overload with: $this->Model->_schema but this didn't work for me so i changed the type in my table of the fields to int.